# Как управлять магией

Tags: php, symfony2

Старый подход

```
$form = $this->createForm(new OnBoardingAgreementType($em), $doc, ["editMode" => true]);
```

Новый подход
**Как сюда в конструктор формы передать $em?**

```
$form = $this->createForm(OnBoardingAgreementType::class, $doc, ["editMode" => true]);
```

Comment: Возможно Вам стоит зарегистрировать форму, как сервис? В документации к формам написано следующее _"This is only needed if your form type requires some dependencies to be injected"_ Пример: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#form-cookbook-form-field-service

Comment: И передать уже там entity manager? Думал об этом, но так получается что все формы нужно регистрировать как сервисы

Comment: Думаю у Вас не получится отдельно Entity Manager в форму передать, т.к. он требует подключения к БД и вызывается через доктрину, поэтому передавайте в сервис доктрину `arguments: ["@doctrine"]`, а в классе формы уже вызывайте энтити менеджер как-нибудь так: `$this->var_for_doctrine_from->getManager();`

Comment: Ок скорее всего так и сделаю

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich если не хочешь создавать форму как сервис, можешь передать оъект EntityManager как опцию к форме. Т.е. в configureOptions() создаеш новую опцию с классом EntityManager, и передаёшь её при вызове createForm

Answer (score 1):

Если ваши формы имеют зависимости вам придется создавать из них сервис. Подход Symfony таков. Просто раньше вы делали не так, как это видели разработчики Symfony и по-этому сейчас у вас возникают проблемы.